# Jackson deserialization: Custom Object factory

Tags: java, json, jackson

How do you implement in Jackson a conversion from json to Java objects, based on class types specified in the json.

Example Java Types:

```
public class Car{
    public String make;
    public String model;
}

public class Spoon {
    public String material;
}

public class Ownership {
    public List<Object> items;
    public User owner;
}
```

Example Json:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "@class": "com.example.Car",
            "make": "Mercedes-Benz",
            "model": "S500"
        },
        {
            "@class": "com.example.Spoon",
            "material": "silver"
        }            
    ],
    "owner": {
        "name": "John"
    }
}
```

Since the number of classes is unknown (users can add any class) it is not possible to use the annotation @JsonSubTypes.

In addition, the json may contain known strongly types classes, like the object User in the example which is serialized using the standard Jackson implementation.

Most of the examples I can find, such as http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance assume the number of subclasses is known, but in my case it is not, users of the framework will add their own.

Ideally the implementation will just resolve types and let Jackson do the rest of the serialization without repeating that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be solved using an annotation on the collection:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS,
              include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
              property = "@class")
public List<Object> items;
```